# How to update column field in mysql with a certain string?

Tags: java, mysql, javafx

I have a MySql database and 2 columns: status and id. The current status is "Available". I want to update the status to "Not Available" at a certain position, given by the id. For example, if id=3, the status from row 3 should update to "Not Available". What I have tried does not update the status field.

I have tried the following, where test_db is the table from the database and status and id are the columns from the table:

```
public static void updateStatusOfBook(String id) {
    try {
        Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(host, username, passwordServer);
        String sql = "UPDATE  test_db set status='Not Available' where id= id";
        PreparedStatement st = connect.prepareStatement(sql);

        st = connect.prepareStatement(sql);
        connect.close();
        st.close();
    }}
```

Comment: How are you looking at the database to verify the change?

Comment: Your problem is `id= id;`. It should be `id = " + id;` You should take scaisEdge approach. It should eliminate these problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not assigned the id value  you need  a param

```
  String sql = "UPDATE  test_db set status='Not Available' where id=  ?";
  PreparedStatement preparedStmt = connect.prepareStatement(sql);
  preparedStmt.setString(1, id);

  preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: I have tried this, but the status is not updating... It is still "Available".

Comment: have you checkd if the value of the id param ??? .. are you suer is a valid integer ..  ?

Comment: Well, the id in my table is varchar, that's why i put string. That is not the problem..